# capture mullti-line groups

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract each `NAME_` group's information using regex (Python3).
For example, I have a text like

```
AB_ NAME_ 111 "fruit";
AB_ EX_ 111 first_fruit "banana";
AB_ EX_ 111 second_fruit_info "Do you like 
apple

or grape?";
AB_ EX_ 111 third_fruit "tomato";
AB_ NAME_ 120 "food";
AB_ NAME_ 130 "clothes";
AB_ EX_ 130 first_clothes "t-shirt";
```

and the result I want to get is three groups:
1)

```
AB_ NAME_ 111 "fruit";
AB_ EX_ 111 first_fruit "banana";
AB_ EX_ 111 second_fruit_info "Do you like 
apple

or grape?";
AB_ EX_ 111 third_fruit "tomato";
```

2. 

```
AB_ NAME_ 120 "food";
```

3. 

```
AB_ NAME_ 130 "clothes";
AB_ EX_ 130 first_clothes "t-shirt";
```

which are split by their ID (`Name_ ID`).

I tried to capture `AB_ NAME_` info followed by zero or more `AB_ EX_` info as below but it failed. I also went with 're.S', 're.M' flags but didn't work well.

```
AB_ NAME_ \d+ .+;\n(AB_ EX_ \d+ (.|\n)+;\n)*
```

Comment: Welcome! Please read [ask] and write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title. For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `re.DOTALL` to make all next line symbols to be matched with `.` and then you can use `findall()` to get all results, like this:

```
import re

text = """AB_ NAME_ 111 "fruit";
AB_ EX_ 111 first_fruit "banana";
AB_ EX_ 111 second_fruit_info "Do you like
apple

or grape?";
AB_ EX_ 111 third_fruit "tomato";
AB_ NAME_ 120 "food";
AB_ NAME_ 130 "clothes";
AB_ EX_ 130 first_clothes "t-shirt";"""

regex = r"AB_ NAME_.*?(?=AB_ NAME_|$)"

print(re.findall(regex, text, re.DOTALL))
```

The regex pattern is this: `AB_ NAME_.*?(?=AB_ NAME_|$)`

This part `(?=AB_ NAME_|$)` searches for the next `AB_ NAME_` or end of the line (in your case end of the entire string).

Comment: The answer is correct, although OP may just require `r"AB_ NAME_.*?(?=AB_ NAME_|$)"` as the grouping is only relevant if they require those parts of the text separately.

Comment: You're right @Grismar, I changed my answer accordingly. Thanks!